# Grease Pencil Animation

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, windows

I am wanting to use the new features of the grease pencil for animation.  I am going to have a sphere that I want to draw facial expressions on top of.  However, it is not very efficient to try to draw directly on the mesh, especially if you are animating the position/rotation of the model.
**Is there a way to draw grease pencil in a 2D window, and then apply that animation to the mesh of my character?**
Please let me know if you need more clarification.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer off of Packtpub.com.  If any of you want to check out the course, it's called "Blender 2.8 Game Character Creation."

His method for being able to draw the face in a window at the same angle was to create a camera that was positioned face on at the head of the figure, and then to parent it to the head bone.

It's at that moment when you think: "Why didn't I think of that?"  You just have to look outside the box, I guess.

Comment: You may wish to accept your own answer to let others know you have resolved this question.  Also here's the link to the blend files https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Blender-2.8-Game-Character-Creation